What the name of this second order linear homogeneous ODE with non constant coefficient?
Let given ODE:
$$y''+50(1+\sin(x))y=0,\qquad -20\leq x\leq 20.$$
This ODE can't solved analytically, so I solve it numerically. This is the plot of solution if given boundary condition $y'(-20)=1 \text{ and } y'(20)=1.$

The solution is like a wave. But I don't know what the name of this ODE. Anyone know what the name of this ODE (maybe, name of founder)?

There is the large class of Hill equations, $y''+qy=0$ with periodic $q$, but this form $y''+(a+b\cos(t))y=0$ is better known as Mathieu equation.
If $b$ is very small, this equation is a common topic in research and exercises in perturbation theory, application of multi-scale approaches, etc. Employing Fourier series one can get systematic calculation using Hill matrices and determinants.
See

Resonance in Mathieu's Equation
Method of multiple scales on Mathieu's equation
Uniform perturbative solutions to the Mathieu equation

and many others.
